# Texture lines in THREE.js

Tags: three.js, textures

I'm trying to texture a large PlaneMesh with an image that's 2126x1219px and am getting some unexpected lines in the result:

[image: closeup of texture with gray lines across image]

There's no lighting in the scene and the camera is set up to have an isometric feel (orthographic camera, located at (-4, 4, 4) looking at (0, 0, 0)).

I'm not sure where to start debugging this and wanted to see if anyone had seen anything similar. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Do you have any other planes which are in the same position as this one pictured? Or is this plane duplicated? I've seen a problem similar to this when two planes overlap each other.

Comment: Do you still see these lines if you set the `minFilter` property of your texture to `THREE.LinearFilter`?

Comment: @danlong That did it! I had a plane with alpha=0 at the same position. I thought that wouldn't be an issue but translating the textured plane up a tiny bit fixed it. Thank you and Mugen87 for the help!

Comment: @SanderMoolin glad it did! I'll add it as an answer in-case anyone else has a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The glitch in the texture, in this case, was caused by another object occupying the same space as the plane in the screenshot. Although the second plane had an alpha of 0, it was still affecting the render output.

Moving the two planes slightly apart can stop this render glitch.